# Building python app and connecting to remote database

Tags: python, database, privacy

I want to write a python app that will contain a connection to remote DB.
The user will be able to log in with a username and password (also from different computers) and get his own information in the app. Therefore I would like the information to be saved on a remote server. Which server I can use for this purpose? Preferably free.

Comment: hey, glad to see you on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like heroku for your hosting. Depending on the database you can probably find a good plugin.

Here are some docs if needed:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/reference

Answer (score 0):

what you're asking is how to build an application/website, you need to have programming knowledge to do that. to store your information you can use one of many databases available like "MySQL", "Postgres", "MariaDB", "MangoDB" and many others.

i recommend you to use [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/) as it's the free equivalent of MySQL.